# Need to extract string from a separator in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please I have a string such as this RemoteAuthorizationTestScope|Start:En Attente Validation|:001|:01195|21/01/2015

I can extract the string from the | symbol using this code

```
var userInfo="RemoteAuthorizationTestScope|Start:En Attente Validation|:001|:01195|21/01/2015"
var entries=userInfo.Split('|');
```

however, there are also text such "Start:En Attente Validation" in the string that needs to be separated, how do I achieve this so that I can have the string separated in this manner.

```
RemoteAuthorizationTestScope
Start
En Attente Validation
001 
01195
21/01/2015
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify multiple characters to split and also remove empty entries. Use the [`String.Split overload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
var entries = userInfo.Split(new []{'|', ':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That will give you

```
RemoteAuthorizationTestScope
Start
En Attente Validation
001 
01195
21/01/2015
```

Comment: This works quite well...also within the string I have this "Start:En Attente Validation" how can I get only string after the column character ':'?

Comment: @user989865, in that particular case first, split it on `|` and then for each returned string check for `:` and split on that, if the returned array length is 2 then returned the second element.

Comment: first replace redundant words with string.Empty, then split it

Answer (score 0):

Including your additional request:

> "Start:En Attente Validation" how can I get only string after the column character ':'?

You can do this in one step with a regex: `\|(?:[^:]*:)?`

```
var userInfo = 
  "RemoteAuthorizationTestScope|Start:En Attente Validation|:001|:01195|21/01/2015";

var entries = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(userInfo, "\\|(?:[^:]*:)?");
```

Results in:

```
String[]
[
   "RemoteAuthorizationTestScope",
   "En Attente Validation",
   "001",
   "01195",
   "21/01/2015"
]
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D5ggvH

Comment: Thanks gremac, one last thing though... for the string "Start:En Attente Validation" is a dynamic string at some point it might only include "Start" or Start:En Attente Validation or "Start:En Attente Validation:Complete" please how can I extract only the "Start" string if this is the only text that exist.

Comment: The example I provided would extract all of those examples; use the dotnetfiddle link to play with the input text. If there was an item that only contained "...|Start:|..." it would be empty.. this is the challenge of this type of thing, I don't know all the possible variations or how robust this needs to be. I'd encourage you to learn and understand the regex so you can adjust yourself as necessary: something like dotnetfiddle (or [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net) if you want a native app) is great for this.